# How to use original echart component in Vue (without using wrapper)

Tags: charts, vue.js

How to use original [echarts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/index.html) instance in Vue without using Vue-echart wrapper like [this](https://github.com/Justineo/vue-echarts) or [this](https://github.com/xlsdg/vue-echarts-v3)?

I've found that using this wrapper causing the chart slower and less responsive. I've seen [sample](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=candlestick-sh-2015) from the original echarts, it is really fast, so I want to use that in my Vue app, but I don't know to do that.